# how to reset notification.number?

Tags: android, notifications, xmpp

I have a problem when I try to reset notification.number, I need count the notifications and display them in badge, everiting works fine, the problem come when I receive a notification and I open it the counter must be 0 but it keep counting I already try n**otification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;** but this is not working, can someone  help me please?

EDIT

```
public static void updateNotification(Context context,
            List<ConverAdp> conversations, ConverAdp currentCon,
            boolean notify) {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        boolean useSubject = preferences.getBoolean("use_subject_in_muc", true);
        boolean showNofifications = preferences.getBoolean("show_notification",
                true);
        boolean vibrate = preferences.getBoolean("vibrate_on_notification",
                true);
        boolean alwaysNotify = preferences.getBoolean(
                "notify_in_conversation_when_highlighted", false);

        if (!showNofifications) {
            mNotificationManager.cancel(2342);
            return;
        }

        String targetUuid = "";

        if ((currentCon != null)
                && (currentCon.obModo() == ConverAdp.MODE_MULTI)
                && (!alwaysNotify)) {
            String nick = currentCon.obtenerMultiUOpciones().obtenerNick();
            Pattern highlight = generateNickHighlightPattern(nick);
            Matcher m = highlight.matcher(currentCon.obtenerUltimomsg()
                    .obtenerBody());
            notify = m.find();
        }

        List<ConverAdp> unread = new ArrayList<ConverAdp>();
        for (ConverAdp conversation : conversations) {
            if (conversation.obModo() == ConverAdp.MODE_MULTI) {
                if ((!conversation.leido())
                        && ((wasHighlighted(conversation) || (alwaysNotify)))) {
                    unread.add(conversation);
                }
            } else {
                if (!conversation.leido()) {
                    unread.add(conversation);
                }
            }
        }
        String ringtone = preferences.getString("notification_ringtone", null);

        //
        int ms = unread.size();
        SharedPreferences spt = context.getSharedPreferences("dr", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = spt.edit();

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context);
        if (unread.size() == 0) {
            x=0;
            editor1.putInt("ky", ms);
            editor1.commit();
            /*String tmpStr10 = "0";
            SharedPreferences preferencias=context.getSharedPreferences("n2otific",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editor=preferencias.edit();
            editor.putString("n2otific", tmpStr10);
            editor.commit();*/
            mNotificationManager.cancel(2342);
            return;
        } else if (unread.size() == 1) {
            editor1.putInt("ky", ms);
            editor1.commit();
            ConverAdp conversation = unread.get(0);
            targetUuid = conversation.getUuid();
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
            //mBuilder.setLargeIcon(UIHelper.getContactPicture(conversation, 64,
                //  context, true));
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(conversation.adquirirNombre(useSubject));
            if (notify) {
                mBuilder.setTicker(conversation.obtenerUltimomsg()
                        .obtenerBodyLeible(context));
            }
            StringBuilder bigText = new StringBuilder();
            List<Msgs> messages = conversation.getMessages();
            String firstLine = "";
            for (int i = messages.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                if (!messages.get(i).esLeido()) {
                    if (i == messages.size() - 1) {
                        firstLine = messages.get(i).obtenerBodyLeible(context);
                        bigText.append(firstLine);
                    } else {
                        firstLine = messages.get(i).obtenerBodyLeible(context);
                        bigText.insert(0, firstLine + "\n");
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            mBuilder.setContentText(firstLine);
            mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(bigText.toString()));

        } else {
            NotificationCompat.InboxStyle style = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
            style.setBigContentTitle(unread.size() + " "
                    + context.getString(R.string.unread_conversations));
            StringBuilder names = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < unread.size(); ++i) {

                targetUuid = unread.get(i).getUuid();
                if (i < unread.size() - 1) {
                    names.append(unread.get(i).adquirirNombre(useSubject) + ", ");
                } else {
                    names.append(unread.get(i).adquirirNombre(useSubject));
                }
                style.addLine(Html.fromHtml("<b>"
                        + unread.get(i).adquirirNombre(useSubject)
                        + "</b> "
                        + unread.get(i).obtenerUltimomsg()
                                .obtenerBodyLeible(context)));
                /*int hg = unread.size()+i;
                Log.e(null,"valor de hg" +hg);
                editor1.putInt("ky", hg);
                editor1.commit();*/


            }
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(unread.size() + " "
                    + context.getString(R.string.unread_conversations));
            mBuilder.setContentText(names.toString());
            mBuilder.setStyle(style);
        }
        if ((currentCon != null) && (notify)) {
            targetUuid = currentCon.getUuid();
        }

        if (unread.size() != 0) {

            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
            if (notify) {
                if (vibrate) {
                    int dat = 70;
                    long[] pattern = { 0, 3 * dat, dat, dat };
                    mBuilder.setVibrate(pattern);
                }
                mBuilder.setLights(0xffffffff, 2000, 4000);
                if (ringtone != null) {
                    mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse(ringtone));
                }
            }

            count++;
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(UcityConversActivity.class);

            Intent viewConversationIntent = new Intent(context,
                    UcityConversActivity.class);
            viewConversationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            viewConversationIntent.putExtra(UcityConversActivity.CONVERSATION,
                    targetUuid);
            viewConversationIntent
                    .setType(UcityConversActivity.VIEW_CONVERSATION);

            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(viewConversationIntent);

            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            Notification notification = mBuilder.build();


             x = notification.number= count;
             notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


            mNotificationManager.notify(2342, notification);

            Log.e(null,"valor de la notificacion" + x);
            editor1.putInt("ky", x);
            editor1.commit();


                }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `count` is some sort of global variable which is not used inside this method.

You probably want to set the notification number to the number of unread messages which is `unread.size()`. What you need is

```
mBuilder.setNumber(unread.size());
```

before you build the notification.

Also you define the `int ms = unread.size()` but almost never use it. If you're not using it get rid of it, it makes the code harder to read. Same goes for `count` and `x`.